# using .includes to find if a the digits in a number are the same digits in a different number (e.g. 21 and 12)

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers, include, compare

I am trying to solve a problem where I have to check if two different numbers contain the same numbers, for example 12 and 21, 34 and 43 and so on. I found this method work out, but it is very complicated and not practical. Any better idea?

```
let num = 3332
let num2 = 3323

let arr = Array.from(num.toString()).map(Number);
let arr2 = Array.from(num2.toString()).map(Number);
if (arr2.includes(arr[0],arr[1],arr[2], arr[3])) {
  console.log("it works")
}
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: `includes` doesn't take multiple arguments like that. It accepts a **single** argument to search for, and an optional starting index. (It has no further parameters after those first two.)

Comment: @TKoL - Hit refresh, the *instant* I hit Add Comment I went *Doh!* and deleted it.

Comment: Should `23` and `323` match?

Comment: @thomalex it's not exactly clear to me the conditions that your function should return true / false for a match or miss. You say 21 and 12 should be a match, but what about 112 and 221?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current test is not accurate because it doesn't check if the `num2` contains *other* numbers as well - for example, `9993332` would match as well.

One possibility is to sort the digits, then check that every digit at an index is equal to every digit in the other array:

```js
const toArr = num => [...String(num)].sort();
const check = (num1, num2) => {
  const arr1 = toArr(num1);
  const arr2 = toArr(num2);
  return arr1.length === arr2.length && arr1.every(
    (digit, i) => arr2[i] === digit
  );
};
console.log(check(3332, 3323));
console.log(check(3332, 9993323));
```

(Once we get [`Array.prototype.equals`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63590182), the above simplifies to `=> toArr(num1).equals(toArr(num2)`)

A less computationally expensive way (but harder to read at a glance) would be to turn each number into an object which counts up frequencies, then compare the objects.

```js
const toObj = num => {
  const obj = {};
  for (const char of String(num)) {
    obj[char] = (obj[char] || 0) + 1;
  }
  return obj;
};
const check = (num1, num2) => {
  const entries1 = Object.entries(toObj(num1));
  const obj2 = toObj(num2);
  return (
    entries1.length === Object.keys(obj2).length &&
    entries1.every(([key, val]) => obj2[key] === val)
  );
};
console.log(check(3332, 3323));
console.log(check(3332, 9993323));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could sort digits get a string and compare with the other string.

```js
function check(a, b) {
    return Array.from(a.toString()).sort().join('') === Array.from(b.toString()).sort().join('');
}

console.log(check(3332, 3323));
console.log(check(117, 771));
console.log(check(113, 771));
```